# Access sub object in COM interface

Tags: c++, pointers, interface, com

I want to get access to a sub object of a COM object. In my example I use the CANoe COM Server.

In my program I create a CAN interface to the CANoe Application. Here is an extract of my code so far and it does exactly what I want:

```
HRESULT result;

//prepare for COM handling...
result = CoInitialize(NULL);

//get CLSID of CANoe...
result = CLSIDFromProgID(L"CANoe.Application", &clsid);


if(SUCCEEDED(result))
{
    //connect to COM interface of CANoe...
    result = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER, IID_IApplication, (void**) &pIApp);

    if(SUCCEEDED(result))

    {
        qDebug() << "COM connection established";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "COM connection error";
    }
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Error: CLSID";
}
```

Now I want to get access to a sub object of the COM Server. For example the Measurement object. I tried it with the method `pIApp->get_UI()`

```
IDispatch* pIDis;
IMeasurement* pIMeasurement;

result = pIApp->get_UI(&pIDis);

pIMeasurement = (IMeasurement*) pIDis;
```

The pointer to the COM object needs to be a pointer of the type IMeasurement, so I can use all the methods defined in the header file. But the method `get_UI` only supports pointer of the type IDispatch. I tried to cast the pointer from type IDispatch to IMeasurement. But the program crashs at runtime.

I also tried to create a new interface directly to the sub object:

```
    result = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER, IID_IMeasurement, (void**) &pIMeasurement);
```

But in this try in the variable result there is saved an error and I can't access the methods of the sub object Measurement.

Where is my mistake and how can I get access to the sub object?

Thank you for all answers and hints!

Comment: Did I miss something, or isn't this what `QueryInterface` is all about? And if you did query for it and NULL was returned (similar to the error in `result` that you really should post here), chances are either the object isn't implementing it *or* you forgot to build the appropriate marshaling proxy/stub ell and register it on the client and server machines respectively.

Comment: Casting a COM interface pointer is *never* correct, you must use QueryInterface() to obtain the pointer.  A property named "UI" seems a very unlikely candidate to supply a measurement, you need to know the object model to get this right.  Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: Even if all you can get is IDispatch, Visual Studio can make working with IDispatch-based interfaces much easier with `#import`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comments. QueryInterface was exactly the keyword I've searched for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @WhozCraig, @Hans Passant and @Eric Brown for the hints in the comments.

I was able to solve my problem with the following code:

```
 IDispatch* pIDispatch;

 //get pointer pIDispatch to Measurement object of CANoe...
 result = pIApp->get_Measurement(&pIDispatch);

 if(SUCCEEDED(result))
 {
    //pointer pIDispatch to pIMeasurement...
    result = pIDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IMeasurement, (void**) &pIMeasurement);

    if(SUCCEEDED(result))
    {
       pIDispatch->Release();

       //work with connection here...

       pIMeasurement->Release();

    }

 }
```

Comment: @sharptooth: Well, I think there is no reason not to use smart pointers. I will use them in coming versions. Thank you! One question only for better understanding: The smart pointers have the single convenience, that I don't need to delete them manually, aren't they? But they don't substitute the need of the method `Release` of the COM objects?

Comment: Special smart pointers such as `CComPtr` and `_com_ptr_t` will `Release()` the object and this will make your code three times cleaner and also exception safe.